# How to Align an Image Vertically in Quatro with RevealJS as Output

Tags: html, css, image, quarto

I have an image which I'd like to have a width of `90%` of the slide.
I also want it to be vertically centered on the slide (Or its container).

I tried something like:

```
## Slide Title

::: {layout="[[-1], [1], [-1]]"}

![](MyImage.svg){fig-align="center" width="90%"}

:::
```

Yet the image is still relatively at the top and doesn't occupy 90% of the width.